# Django webrequests

Tags: python, django, webrequest

I want to make blog engine with django. In this process i need to make a specific subdomain for each blog.
Now i faced to a problem that i need a function like django core functions which listen for requests and check for subdomain and path of url that i have written in middleware.
if anybody knows that how write function for checking requests or insert a parameter to "urls.py" url caller for subdomain for instance:

```
`url(r'^/login/$', 'blog_ali.views.login', name='login_blog_ali',*subdomain = "blog_ali"))`
```

is it possible to add subdomain or sth like that or must make a function?
Thanks  and Bye!!!

Comment: Why do you think you need a "request listener"? Django is already doing that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think that there was misunderstanding. I mean that it is impossible to insert subdomain argument to url function with no api installed. I wants to django listener checks url request subdomain and call one of my functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [django-subdomains](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? It seems to do exactly what you're looking for.

Edit: BTW, make sure you've properly configured your web server and your DNS, so any subdomain is mapped to your web app.

Comment: Thanks sir, I have checked it and worked some how but i have some problems with , may be I could not configure it correctly but it seems that it can not support a request listener function in urls.py or any where. Again thanks for your answer it helped me somehow.